# Disable Registration Email in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is it possible to disable the new registration email that gets sent to new users after they register in DNN?

I'm currently sending a custom notification another way, and don't want this message to go out.

I'm referring to these keys:
EMAIL_USER_REGISTRATION_VERIFIED_BODY
EMAIL_USER_REGISTRATION_PUBLIC_BODY

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tracked it down in source code for version 7.0.1, the notification is currently hard coded.

In Registration.ascx.cs, method CreateUser:

```
// The "true" tells the application to send the email
string strMessage = CompleteUserCreation(CreateStatus, user, true, IsRegister);
```